# Make sharepoint table column readonly

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I need to disallow editing of one calculated column in sharepoint list's table view. Let's consider a list with fields

- Price: Number
- Quantity: Number
- Total: =[Price]*[Quantity]

`bool Microsoft.SharePoint.SPField.ReadOnlyField` is by default `true` for the field `Total`, however I am able to edit the formula. Setting the property to `false` changes nothing, I still can edit the formula. Setting the property to `true` for the other two numeric fields, for which it is `false` by default, does work. XML schema for the `Total` field is

```
<Field Type="Calculated" DisplayName="Total" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" 
Indexed="FALSE" Format="DateOnly" LCID="1049" ResultType="Number" 
ReadOnly="TRUE" ID="{44447323-0826-4389-8e4b-d4c11c14a45a}" SourceID="
{b6514d3e-3789-4354-97af-94e915562a35}" StaticName="_x0442__x0440__x0438_" 
Name="_x0442__x0440__x0438_" ColName="sql_variant1" RowOrdinal="0" 
Version="4">
    <Formula>=_x043e__x0434__x0438__x043d_*_x0434__x0432__x0430_</Formula>
    <FieldRefs>
        <FieldRef Name="_x0434__x0432__x0430_" />
        <FieldRef Name="_x043e__x0434__x0438__x043d_" />
    </FieldRefs>
</Field>
```

I have also found a client-side method of doing it with jQuery as follows:

```
$("input[title='Metrics ID']").attr("readonly","true").css('background-color','#F6F6F6');
```

, but I am unable to find a DOM element, that would reseble anything close to that field. Could you please give me any advice?

Comment: Try using $("input[title='Metrics ID']").prop("readonly"); if you  jquery version >= 1.6

Comment: @Shiladitya but what is `Metrics ID`? `$('input[title="Metrics ID"]')` is null, where can I find out the title of the corresponding input?

Comment: It's an attribute value & the attribute name is title

Comment: Move mouse over the column > right click > inspect element > find the id of metrics. If there's no id use the tables class and nth child

Comment: @Shiladitya yes, I am aware of the way jQuery searches th DOM, but where does that `Metrics ID` come from? On the example that I got this jQuery line from, the column name was `Project ID` and it wasn't a calculated column

Comment: @user5014677 I've tried that, but the sharepoint's context menu overrides my browser's context menu

Comment: What do you mean by that? Are you doing your queries from a scripteditor?

Comment: I am trying to test via developer's console to see if anything works, but right-clicking on a column gives the context menu with options `Add column` etc., instead of default browser CM

Comment: Oh yeah i see i had that problem too. You can right click like above or below the table to get the browser default right click options. And then hover the mouse over the elements until you find the content that contains the table, then open it hover again until you find the table and so on. In chrome/firefox hovering on a element hightlights it on the page so it's easier to find that way.